# how get each value from json file

Tags: javascript, json, datatables, cakephp-2.6

I try to send data to datatable in json file like bellow:
exemple data of my json file:

```
"responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"vba",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"name,role_t,born,natio_t",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "name":"Khouli",
        "born":["1978-04-03T00:00:00Z"],
        "natio_t":"tunisien",
        "role_t":"Consultant"},
      {
        "name":"Atayi",
        "born":["1987-06-24T00:00:00Z"],
        "natio_t":"Francaise",
        "role_t":"Consultant"}
}
```

That is my function:

```
$ ( document ).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../search.json',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
            var body = "<tr>";
            body    += "<td>" + data.name + "</td>";
            body    += "<td>" + data.born + "</td>";
            body    += "<td>" + data.natio_t + "</td>";
            body    += "<td>" + data.role_t + "</td>";

            body    += "</tr>";
            $('.datatable-ajax-source table').append(body);
        });
```

But I get table with undifined value
[image: this is my table result]

how to get this value from json files

Comment: Your JSON data is invalid in different ways. Please post valid JSON.

Comment: clearly `data` isn't an array. why you would treat it like one is beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input data seems to be wrong: Corrected data here:

```
{
"responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "q":"vba",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"name,role_t,born,natio_t",
      "wt":"json"}},
      "response":{"numFound":7,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "name":"Khouli",
        "born":["1978-04-03T00:00:00Z"],
        "natio_t":"tunisien",
        "role_t":"Consultant"},
      {
        "name":"Atayi",
        "born":["1987-06-24T00:00:00Z"],
        "natio_t":"Francaise",
        "role_t":"Consultant"}
     ]
}
}
```

The proper JS to handle this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '../search.json',
success: function(data) {
    // Data is the root node of your json response.
    // You need to navigate through the "docs" node.
    if(data.response.docs && data.response.docs.length > 0)
    {
    $.each(data.response.docs, function(i, item) {
        var body = "<tr>";

        body    += "<td>" + item.name + "</td>";
        body    += "<td>" + item.born + "</td>";
        body    += "<td>" + item.natio_t + "</td>";
        body    += "<td>" + item.role_t + "</td>";

        body    += "</tr>";
        $('.datatable-ajax-source table').append(body);
    }
    });
```

You are not getting the proper value for `data`.
You should get the `docs.data[i]` which is, in this case, `item` as defined in the `.each()`.

Comment: thank you @DidierAupest your answer make since But when i try this solution i get this ERROR jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefinedeach @ jquery.min.js:4success @ application.js:111c @ jquery.min.js:4fireWith @ jquery.min.js:4k @ jquery.min.js:6r @ jquery.min.js:6

Comment: it's still the same error  application.js:116 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in this ligne if(data.response.docs && data.docs.length > 0)

Comment: I fix it thank you for your help: I just inspire or your advice and i replace data.docs with data.response.docs and its working now .

Comment: I forgot to apply this changes everywhere !

Answer (score -2):

You didn't tell jquery that you're expecting json back, so it accepted the JSON string from the server's response as plaintext, and passes it into `data` as plain text.

Either use `.getJSON()`, which will auto-parse the response into a native JS data structure, or

```
$.ajax(
  ...
   dataType: "json"
  ...
);
```

Comment: True that that could be part of the issue, but if the server sets the `Content-Type` header properly, jQuery should parse it. Either way, from what I can tell, he needs to traverse deeper into the structure, which currently is invalid.